# How to make alias to systemctl with autocomplete

Tags: bash, alias, auto-completion

I tried

```
alias sct='systemctl'
complete -F _systemctl sct
```

But the function _systemctl is not found until I run the original command systemctl in the session. This function loads dynamically or somehow and contains many other same functions inside.

OS - Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a file named `/etc/bash_completion.d/systemctl`:

```
if [[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl ]]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl && complete -F _systemctl systemctl sct
fi
```

<sup>You can restart bash-completion by sourcing `. /etc/bash_completion`</sup>

Comment: I had been wondering about this for some time - thanks for a good solution. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I found a file with autocomplete functions for systemctl in my system and added a line to load it:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl
alias sct='systemctl'
complete -F _systemctl sct
```

Comment: where did you put it?

Comment: @bac0n In the terminal. Or in ~/.bashrc file in my case.

Comment: no need for an alias.

Comment: I thought so, but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: yep wrong of me.

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
alias sct='systemctl'
_completion_loader systemctl
complete -F _systemctl sct
```

But I recommend use bash function instead of bash alias so you can define some shortcuts for sub commands, here is an example:

```
sct ()
{
    case $1 in
        e)
            shift;
            sudo systemctl enable --now "$@"
        ;;
        d)
            shift;
            sudo systemctl disable --now "$@"
        ;;
        s)
            shift;
            systemctl status "$@"
        ;;
        S)
            shift;
            sudo systemctl stop "$@"
        ;;
        r)
            shift;
            sudo systemctl restart "$@"
        ;;
        *)
            systemctl "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

In addition, in order to make bash completion work for these shortcuts, you need to add them to array `VERBS` in corresponding keys in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl`. Here is an example for `sct e` :

```
    local -A VERBS=(
        ...
-       [DISABLED_UNITS]='enable'
+       [DISABLED_UNITS]='enable e'
        ...
    )
```

But these modifications in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl` may lost over an update. I haven't found a perfect way to override it yet, maybe later.